# Why a service in init.d and not in rc*.d started?

Tags: startup, services, init, init.d

I have a configured and working service script `myservice` in the `/etc/init.d` and in `/etc/rc*.d` directories of an Ubuntu 13.10 distribution.

Removing the links in `/etc/rc*.d` using `update-rc.d -f myservice remove` doesnt'remove the service after a reboot. What am I missing here and how should I properly add/remove services on this Ubuntu distribution ?

Comment: Did you check manually that the links were well removed from the `/etc/rc*.d` directories ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [update-rc.d manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man8/update-rc.d.8.html):

> When  invoked  with the remove option, update-rc.d removes any links
>   in  the /etc/rcrunlevel.d directories to the script /etc/init.d/name. 
>   The  script  must have been deleted already.  If the script is still
>   present  then update-rc.d aborts with an error message.

So you should remove your script in `/ect/init.d` before you run `update-rc.d` command.